# Is it ok to use `-myNumber` to negate a number in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, syntax

Not sure why people are so aggressive on the downvotes

I'm curious because `-2 ** 2` is invalid, which I would expect to be either `-1 * Math.pow(2, 2)` or `Math.pow(-2, 2)` but not neither

---

We're currently writing many math equations using JavaScript, and I'm wondering if there is anything to worry about with regards to using `-t` for example.

Does this always perform `-1 * t`, regardless of placement in the expression?

Eg: `console.log(Math.sin(-value))`

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly valid.

Comment: I don't know why you would expect problems with this, of all things.

Comment: @user2357112 please see the edit, this question is well founded because Javascript allows addition/multiplication of truthy (1) and falsey (0) values (like an electric circuit), but I don't know how subtraction works

Comment: "Javascript allows addition/multiplication of truthy (1) and falsey (0) values" - if you mean specifically 1 and 0, of course you can add and multiply those. That has nothing to do with truthiness. If you're under the impression that Javascript interprets addition and multiplication as boolean OR and AND under some circumstances, it doesn't do that. `true+true` is `2`, not `true`, and `1+(-1)` is falsey despite both operands being truthy.

Comment: @user2357112—whether `-` does subtraction or type conversion is based on context, so it's reasonable to ask about that.

Comment: @RobG: You're going to have to clarify what you mean by that. It sounds like you're saying that `-` is a subtraction operator in some contexts and a type conversion operator in other contexts, and that sounds absurd. `-` coerces its arguments to Numbers and then performs either negation or subtraction, depending on whether you're using it as a unary or binary operator.

Comment: @user2357112— "*…depending on whether you're using it as a unary or binary operator*". Exactly. `-` is just a punctuator, its meaning comes from the surrounding code (context). The OP is just asking whether `-1*3` is ever equivalent to `-(1*3)`, or is always `(-1) * 3` (noting that the outcome is the same in that example).

Comment: @user2357112 Javascript does interpret addition (`else`, `||`, `:`) and multiplication (`if`, `&&`, `?`) based truthiness, where 0 is false, anything else is true. `(0 + 1 * 0) === (0 || 1 && 0)`

Comment: @neaumusic: No, that's completely wrong. You'll find that `(1 + 1) !== (1 || 1)`.

Comment: @user2357112 the answer is yes, you  can write expressions with mathematical operators, short circuit operators, maps, if / else statements, bitwise manipulation, and ternaries, it's all routing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole purpose of the unary `-` operator is to negate a number value. From the [spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-unary-minus-operator):

> The unary - operator converts its operand to Number type and then negates it.

So yes, you should absolute use it for negating a number value.

Comment: I believe there was some debate about whether `-2 ** 2` is supposed to be treated as `-(2 ** 2)` or `(-2) ** 2` but no consensus was found. So they left it to the author to specify the precedence (the last two work).

Comment: It doesn't work because Javascript doesn't *have* a `**` operator.

Comment: @user2357112: It was introduced in ES2016: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-exp-operator .

Comment: @user2357112: Yep :) There weren't many changes this year, but that was one of them.

Comment: The exponentiation operator `**` and assignment operator `**=` aren't well supported yet so not really suitable for general use at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

It's a perfectly valid **unary operator**! Yes, unary operators don't need two elements. Some examples for you:

```js
// Parameter
console.log(new Date(-1000 * -500));
// Value
var a = -75;
console.log(a);
// Expression
var b = -2 * 15;
console.log(b);
```